# Reading file into 2D array with unknown dimensions - Java

Tags: java, arrays

The task at hand is to read in a file with unspecified dimensions... The only stipulation I have with completing this task is that I'm only allowed to use Arrays - no arraylists, lists, maps, trees, or anything else of the sort... just arrays.

Yes, I sneaked at a sample txt file and it showed values such as :

```
0 2 3.0
1 0 2.0
2 1 7.0
2 3 1.0
3 0 6.0
```

But this isn't to say all possible files tested with my code in the future will be the same dimensions.

- I have tried normal .hasNext() operations to count how many elements there were in the file, but I haven't been able to find a way to count the number of rows and columns collectively.
- I'm a beginner and am not sure how to do this. I have seen examples with bufferedreader but can't comprehend the use of it and the functions within that class to use it without being oblivious to what it's actually doing.

Code:

```
public void loadDistances(String fname) throws Exception {
    String file = fname;
    File f = new File(file);
    Scanner in = null;

    try {
        in = new Scanner(f);
    }
    catch (FileNotFoundException ex) {
        System.out.println("Can't find file " + file);
        System.exit(1);
    }

    int rows = 0;
    int cols = 0;

    while(in.hasNextLine()) {
        rows++;
        while(in.hasNextDouble()){
            cols++;
            // statement here which will close once reads a "end of line" character?
            // or something of the sorts
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What have you tried? What problem are you having? You need to ask a more specific question.

Comment: Read the file twice. You get the dimensions the first time, the 2nd time you put the items into the array you create with those dimensions.

Comment: Throw together some code using the examples you have found, and post it with a question. Something like "Why am I getting X error in this code?" It will give us something to work with and show that you've tried something. As this question stands currently the only answer we could give is writing the code for you or something too vague to really be of any help. And we really really do like to help!

Comment: @Shaded Added some code

Answer (score 0):

try to find oud the dimensions before you are defining an array...
the number of lines could be counted with something like the following snipped:

```
public int countDimensions(String mytxtFile) throws IOException {
    InputStream contentOfFile = new BufferedInputStream(new FileInputStream(mytxtFile));
    try {
        byte[] a = new byte[1024];
        int counter = 0;
        int readMyChars = 0;
        boolean emptyfile = true;
        while ((readMyChars = contentOfFile.read(a)) != -1) {
            emptyfile = false;
            for (int i = 0; i < readMyChars; ++i) {
                if (a[i] == '\n') { ++counter;}}
        }
        return (counter == 0 && !emptyfile) ? 1 : counter;
    } finally {contentOfFile.close();}
}
```

-now you have got a first dimension for your array...

the number of elements in a row could be defined by counting a "seperator" in a line, like spaces, or a special letter...
I do not know how you want to put the data into the array, or what you want to do with the data...but this could work if i understood you correctly...

BUT NOTE: this whole solution is not very aesthetic & efficient and not recommended.